# Can anybody recommend some organic farms for volunteering on the Canary Islands?

Tags: spain, backpacking, volunteering, canary-islands, wwoof

The coming two years I will combine studying (permaculture) and backpacking through Europe while volunteering on organic farms. Can anyone recommend some farms on La Palma, one of the Canary Islands?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals [a number of results for `wwoof la palma`](https://www.google.fr/search?q=wwoof%20la%20palma&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VnNLVbfAFMv7UtbYgOgH). These include blog stories of [people who have actually volunteered](https://www.travelblog.org/Europe/Spain/Canary-Islands/La-Palma/blog-471778.html), as well as WWOOF farms in La Palma ([here is a random result](http://www.finca-la-paz.com/finca-e.html)). For more information on the topic I would suggest you look on [the WWOOF España website](http://ruralvolunteers.org/WHOSTS/).